# FullCalendar doesn't load body properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

The problem is basically that fullcalendar doensn't load properly. It works in some browsers but not in others. Example: works in Chrome on Ubuntu but doesn't in Chrome on Windows.

Error:

[image]

Working:

[image]

Here is some of my code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#medicalen").fullCalendar({
        allDaySlot: false,
        nowIndicator: true,
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        lang: 'es',
        slotLabelFormat: 'H:mm',
        titleFormat: "D MMMM 'YY",
        height: 'parent',
        displayEventTime: false,
        slotLabelInterval: '00:10:00',
        hiddenDays: [0,6],
        events: [{'title': 'JOHNSON CAMILA LUCIA', 'start': '2019-04-29 18:00', 'pac_id': 1345}, {'title': 'PATHEVEN SANTIAGO', 'start': '2019-04-25 12:00', 'pac_id': 4512}, {'title': 'CIARALLE JUAN ESTEBAN', 'start': '2019-04-29 16:00', 'pac_id': 106}],
        slotDuration: '00:10:00',
        defaultTimedEventDuration: '00:10:00',
        views:{
            agenda:{
                minTime: '8:30',
                maxTime: '18:00',
            }
        },
        eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view){
                          loadhis(event.pac_id);
                    }
    });        
});
```

I already tried with the `render` method and it's the same. I don't have any console error or log error. This worked properly 1 month ago. It's been always hosted on PythonAnywhere, made with Flask 1.0 and Python 3.7.

Comment: Within 1 month, have you update any jQuery files?

Comment: chrome is pretty much the same on each desktop OS. Maybe your version of Chrome itself is different on those two machines? And...have you checked in your browser's Console for errors, on the one where you have problems? Also do you have problems in any other browsers / platforms / versions? How widely have you tested this, exactly?

Comment: Unfortunately, since you are using some server-side code in your example above, we can't use your code to test it ourselves. But perhaps if you post a new version of your code with those values replaced with the generated values (you can use the View Source feature of your browser to see the end result) then we could try this out and see if we can reproduce it.

Comment: @ADyson Now it's edited with real code to try. I realize that it works perfectly in Chrome 72 but doesn't in Chrome 74. Any help?

Comment: Just created a JSFiddle as a demo (using fullCalendar 3.10 and the latest momentJS and jQuery). You're right, there's a strange error in Chrome 74: http://jsfiddle.net/L952ce4j/ . It also seems to fail in IE11, and in Firefox 66 however. (This is on Windows 7)

Comment: But if you comment out the `height: 'parent'` line then it's fine: http://jsfiddle.net/L952ce4j/1/

Comment: If you put the calendar inside a full-height container element, as per the demo linked from the [documentation page](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/height) then it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/L952ce4j/2/ . I haven't studied the list of changes in the latest Chrome (please feel free to do so!) but maybe something has altered which changes rules about the default height of things. Although the fact it also failed in IE11, which hasn't been updated for a while, does cast doubt on that. Are you **sure** you're running the exact same code in all your tests?

Comment: You are right! I commented it and it's now working. Yes, I always run the same code because it's a website hosted in PythonAnywhere. Thank you so much ADyson!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove

```
height: 'parent'
```

then you'll have no problems.

Since the calendar is not within a fixed-height block, then it will adopt the minimum height of the parent block, and so some of the calendar will not be visible.